# some days the pigeon, some days the statue

Tags: expressions, metaphors

There is a common expression in english - "some days the pigeon, and some days the statue". The meaning is self explanatory- Certain days go really well, while other days are pathetic.

Can you guys tell me other such equivalent phrases in English? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One day you can be a rooster, the next a feather duster". I've heard it on a number of occasions over the years but the first time I can recall hearing it was from "Captain" Peter Janson, at the time a touring car racing driver, just before the Bathurst 1000 race some time in the late 1970's.

(I doubt that he invented it, though.)

Comment: wow perfect! I was looking at such examples.